# Create seprate File for validation, so that I can use it in different component

Tags: angular

I am very new to `angular 7` I created a from to add new teacher it contain different fields and every field have validation, I have a file

```
add-teacher.component.ts
```

it contain the all the logic to add the teacher and also the validation but, I want to create a different file for validation so that in future i can use this validation file for add-student, Right now I am using this way to validate:

**add-teacher.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-teacher',
  templateUrl: './add-teacher.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-teacher.component.css']
})
export class AddTeacherComponent implements OnInit {

  teachers: Teacher[] = [];

  teachersValidation = new FormGroup({
    userName: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required
    ]),
    fullName: new FormControl('',[
      Validators.required
    ]),
    branch: new FormControl('',[
      Validators.required
    ]),
    subject: new FormControl('',[
      Validators.required
    ]),
    semester: new FormControl('',[
      Validators.required
    ]),
    password: new FormControl('',[
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern("(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&].{8,}")
    ])
  })

  get validations() {
    return this.teachersValidation.controls;
  }
}
```

**add-teacher.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group" #userform="ngForm" [formGroup]="teachersValidation">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">user name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" 
          [(ngModel)]="teachers.userName" name="userName" placeholder="Enter User Name" formControlName="userName">
          <div *ngIf="(validations.userName.invalid && validations.userName.touched) || validations.userName.dirty">
              <small *ngIf="validations.userName.errors?.required" class="text-danger">Name is required</small>
              <!--question mark(?) is a safe navigation operator-->
              <small *ngIf="validations.userName.errors?.pattern" class="text-danger">Please provide a valid password</small>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" #userform="ngForm" [formGroup]="teachersValidation">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Full Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" 
          [(ngModel)]="teachers.fullName" name="fullName" placeholder="Enter User Name" formControlName="fullName">
          <div *ngIf="(validations.fullName.invalid && validations.fullName.touched) || validations.fullName.dirty">
              <small *ngIf="validations.fullName.errors?.required" class="text-danger">Full Name is required</small>
              <!--question mark(?) is a safe navigation operator-->
            </div>
        </div>

----------------------------
```

so can you please provide me a code which use same type of validation but in a different file so that i can call its methods whenever i want.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read about custom validations in Angular. You can get idea from there.You can create a generic validation functions and apply whenever needed.

Have a look to below look

https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators

https://www.positronx.io/angular-8-custom-validation-tutorial-with-examples/